# Error occurred in cli "Cannot find module at Function.Module._resolveFilename"

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to host my node application but when I run the command

```
heroku -v
```

or

```
tsc
```

it is giving me Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\pnpm-global\1\node_modules\heroku\bin\run'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename

I have reinstall heroku but couldn't resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling node and every other package, still could not get rid of the error. Finally I run the registry cleaner software that cleaned the registry and allow me to do my work.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue and found invalid `path` in `import module`

Automatically assigned path was invalid then I corrected it and got issue removed.